# Purposeful Eyebrows

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does purposeful eyebrows mean in this sentence?

> She thought for a moment. Then she pressed a hand to her heart again and lifted those straight, purposeful eyebrows.

Comment: Hi Hatim, do add a link to where you found this, or add a little more from the source. This context needs a bit more content. Cheers !

Comment: There is some meaning (purpose) behind how her eyebrows looked, but more context is needed to know what that is.

Comment: Seems more lit crit than learning English.... But as I'm undecided I'll just comment instead of vtc-ing.

Answer (score 3):

*She thought for a moment* (coming to a decision, perhaps) *and lifted those straight, purposeful eyebrows* (showing determination or resolve).